Js Equal Distribution Algorithm of Users in Groups
That given n users with v value divide the users into g groups, so that the value of the sum of the values of the users of each group is similar, the number of users per group must be equal to the more can differ about a user:
const users = [{
        name: 'a',
        value: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'b',
        value: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'c',
        value: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'd',
        value: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'e',
        value: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'f',
        value: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'g',
        value: 7
    },
    {
        name: 'h',
        value: 8
    },
    {
        name: 'i',
        value: 9
    }
];

const numGroups = 3;
const groupedUsers = divideUsersIntoGroups(users, numGroups);

const result = [
    [
        users: [{
            name: 'a',
            value: 1
        }, {
            name: 'e',
            value: 5
        }, {
            name: 'i',
            value: 9
        }]
        valueTot: 15
    ],
    [
        users: [{
            name: 'b',
            value: 2
        }, {
            name: 'f',
            value: 6
        }, {
            name: 'g',
            value: 7
        }]
        valueTot: 15
    ],
    [
        users: [{
            name: 'c',
            value: 3
        }, {
            name: 'd',
            value: 4
        }, {
            name: 'h',
            value: 8
        }]
        valueTot: 15
    ]
];

I'm using the following algorithm but I'm not getting the desired result.
function divideUsersIntoGroups(users, numGroups) {
users.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

const groupedUsers = Array.from({ length: numGroups }, () => []);

users.forEach((user, index) => {
const groupIndex = index % numGroups;
groupedUsers[groupIndex].push(user);
});

return groupedUsers;
}

Or
function divideUsersIntoGroups(users, numGroups) {
    // Step 1: Calculate the total sum of values in the users list
    const totalSum = users.reduce((acc, user) => acc + user.value, 0);

    // Step 2: Determine the target sum for each group
    const targetSum = totalSum / numGroups;

    // Step 3: Sort the users list based on their values
    users.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

    // Step 4: Initialize an array to store the groups
    const groupedUsers = Array.from({ length: numGroups }, () => ({ users: [], valueTot: 0 }));

    // Step 5 & 6: Assign users to groups based on closest total value to target sum
    users.forEach(user => {
        let minDiff = Infinity;
        let bestGroupIndex = 0;

        groupedUsers.forEach((group, index) => {
            const currentDiff = Math.abs(group.valueTot + user.value - targetSum);
            if (currentDiff < minDiff) {
                minDiff = currentDiff;
                bestGroupIndex = index;
            }
        });

        groupedUsers[bestGroupIndex].users.push(user);
        groupedUsers[bestGroupIndex].valueTot += user.value;
    });

    return groupedUsers;
}

Other possible inputs:
 const users = [
       { name: 'a', value: 1 },
       { name: 'b', value: 2 },
       { name: 'c', value: 3 },
       { name: 'd', value: 24 },
       { name: 'e', value: 30 },
       { name: 'f', value: 50 },
];

const result = [
    [
        users: [{
            name: 'f',
            value: 50
        }, {
            name: 'a',
            value: 1
        }]
        valueTot: 51
    ],
    [
        users: [{
            name: 'e',
            value: 30
        }, {
            name: 'b',
            value: 2
        }]
        valueTot: 32
    ],
    [
        users: [{
            name: 'd',
            value: 24
        }, {
            name: 'c',
            value: 3
        }]
        valueTot: 27
    ]
]

 const users = [
       { name: 'a', value: -5 },
       { name: 'b', value: -2 },
       { name: 'c', value: 0 },
       { name: 'd', value: 0 },
       { name: 'e', value: 3 },
       { name: 'f', value: 5 },
       { name: 'g', value: 8 },
       { name: 'h', value: 9 },
       { name: 'i', value: 9 },
       { name: 'j', value: 10 },
       { name: 'k', value: 34 }
];

const result = [
    [
        users: [{
                name: 'k',
                value: 34
            },
            {
                name: 'a',
                value: -5
            },
            {
                name: 'b',
                value: -2
            },
            {
                name: 'c',
                value: 0
            }
        ],
        valueTot: 27
    ],
    [
        users: [{
                name: 'j',
                value: 10
            },
            {
                name: 'i',
                value: 9
            },
            {
                name: 'e',
                value: 3
            },
            {
                name: 'd',
                value: 0
            },
        ],
        valueTot: 22
    ],
    [
        users: [{
                name: 'h',
                value: 9
            },
            {
                name: 'g',
                value: 8
            },
            {
                name: 'f',
                value: 5
            },
        ],
        valueTot: 22
    ],
]


Are you after the best fit here? Or would there be a tolerance? For example if you can divide in several ways, option one gives you groups with a sum of 12 and 14 (difference of two), the other 11 and 15 (difference of 4) - with best fit, the first option is preferable - with difference as close to zero as possible. The tolerance might allow some deviation up to a point, e.g., any difference up to 5 or similar.

Also, are the values always monotonic? Or are they supposed to be random? With monotonic algebraic sequences, it's probably easier to partition into same or similar sums. But otherwise, more analysis of the data would be needed.

@AlexanderNenashev: I tried the algorithm you wrote, it doesn't work for me, it doesn't give me the desired result.

@VLAZ: The values are random, this is just a case of the values increasing by 1.
The values should be, for example, a sum of money, try to make the difference between the groups tend towards zero.

@Paul OK, that's what I expected. Just wanted to clarify.

What does this phrase mean? "the number of users per group must be equal to the more can differ about a user:"

@MattMorgan: If there are 9 users and I have to divide them into 3 groups, each group has 3 users.
If there are 10 users and I have to divide them into 3 groups, the groups are made up of 3,3,4 users.
If there are 11 users and I have to divide them into 3 groups, the groups are made up of 3,4,4 users.
I don't know if I explained myself well.

Hmm, if you need the groups to have equal users, then you might not get optimal sum. For example something like 50, 24, 30, 1, 2, 3 divided into three groups would mean two users per group but a better grouping (in terms of sum) might be [50] [24, 1, 2, 3] [30] as then the difference between the three should be the smallest

@VLAZ: I don't need the optimal sum, I need it to be as fair as possible, in this case divide like this:
[
[50,1],
[30,2],
[24,3]
]
I don't know if I explained what I mean.

OK, got it now. Initially I thought the grouping was sum-driven only.

@VLAZ: I have included other possible different inputs if you are interested, with the possible desired result.

@VLAZ: I was thinking if this could be a possible solution but I don't know. https://pastebin.com/DJNcYuBA

This problem includes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem as a special case. Therefore it is strongly NP hard. No fast algorithms exist. Not even if you try tricks like dynamic programming. So which do you prefer? Fast and fallible? Or really slow?

@btilly: For really slow what order of time are they talking about?

@Paul Nothing subexponential is known. Not even pseudo-polynomial.

You could take a brute force approach by checking all possible combinations.
To find the best result it checks the variance of length and sum and take the best (the once with smaller values) as result.
It works actually without having a sum or a count of elements for each bucket.


const
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    sum = a => a.reduce(add, 0),
    variance = values => {
        const
            average = sum(values) / values.length;

        return values.reduce((t, v) => t + (v - average) ** 2, 0) / values.length;
    };

function subset(values, groups) {
        
    function getStatistics(result) {
        return {
            varianceLength: variance(result.map(({ length }) => length)),
            varianceSum: variance(result.map(sum))
        };
    }

    function iter(left, right) {
        if (!left.length) {
            const row = { right: right.map(a => [...a]), ...getStatistics(right) };
            if (row.varianceLength === min.varianceLength && row.varianceSum === min.varianceSum ) {
                result.push(row);
            } else if (row.varianceLength <= min.varianceLength && row.varianceSum <= min.varianceSum ) {
                result = [row];
                min.varianceLength = Math.min(min.varianceLength, row.varianceLength);
                min.varianceSum = Math.min(min.varianceSum, row.varianceSum);
            }
            return;
        }
        
        for (let i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
            const
                subArray = [...right[i], left[0]];
                
            iter(left.slice(1), right.with(i, subArray));
        }
    }
    
    let result = [],
        min = { varianceLength: Infinity, varianceSum: Infinity };
        
    iter(values.toSorted((a, b) => b - a), Array.from({ length: groups }, _ => []));
    console.log('length:', result.length); // all permutations
    return result;
}

console.log(subset([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 3));
console.log(subset([1, 2, 3, 24, 30, 50], 3));
console.log(subset([-5, -2, 0, 0, 3, 5, 8, 9, 9, 10, 34], 3));
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




You don't know sum. Above I have put other possible inputs.

@Paul, you need to give some objective to optimize the result, either to have same count of slots, count of element and equal sum. if this is not possible, you need to declare either the count of elements or sum.

The element count is specified above.
